# Export to pdf in asp.net + vb.net using itextsharp

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, itext, export-to-pdf

I am trying to export gridview(HTML Based) to a pdf in asp.net+vb.net(backend). When I click on the Export to PDF button the download window shows, but when you click on open Adobe reader will open but displays the message

**" Adobe Reader Could not open 'test[1].pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged ( for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded) "**.

The coding for export to pdf is same for 5 different reports of which 4 are working fine, as well as export to `Excel` is also working fine for all 5 reports. I searched on google but was not able to find the correct answer. Does it have any relation with the itextsharp dll version? ( I am using  itextsharp version 3.1.1.0)

Comment: the problem may be in the data, perhaps there are some string with a wrong charset...

Comment: You are going to have to give us a lot more to work with, right now we don't have much.

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem commonly occurs with ASP.NET web forms when you fail to **explicitly** call `Response.End()` **immediately** after you call the `Document` object's  `Close()` method. When you fail to call `Response.End()`, the web form appends it's HTML markup to the PDF output stream and corrupts the document.

You can verify this by saving the PDF to a local drive and opening it with any text editor.